# Angular 10 :Correct one of the identical sub-expressions on both sides of operator "-"

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube

i have this message 'Correct one of the identical sub-expressions on both sides of operator "-"' in sonar .

```
calculatePercent() {
if (this.#oldValue === 0) {
  this.percentage = 1;
  this.showPercentage = this.percentage;
} else {
  this.percentage = (this.#newValue - this.#oldValue) / this.#oldValue;
  if (this.percentage >= 0) {
    this.showPercentage = this.percentage;
  } else {
    this.showPercentage = -this.percentage;
  }
}
```

}